# Writing in Google App Engine Buckets alternative for AdWords reports

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage, google-ads-api

I'm making an app using AdWords API with Java and I have an issue writing a file into Google App Engine's default bucket. I found the [Read-Write](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/googlecloudstorageclient/read-write-to-cloud-storage) to Cloud Storage documentation but I'm not making it from my main class. I don't really understand the doGet method (which I assumed is the main method for the GAE environment)

Is there an alternative for the following code in Google AdWords to write in the Google Cloud Buckets?

```
      ReportDownloadResponse response =
          new ReportDownloader(session).downloadReport(reportDefinition);

      response.saveToFile(reportFile);
```

Also if someone can clarify the doGet and doPost methods, can I have one on every class if I'm writting multiple reports, and do I just call them like the other fuctions? `doGet()` and `doPost()`?

Answer (score 0):

Short Answer: no, I couldn't find an alternative to ReportDownloadResponse easy method.

Long Answer:
I used the AWQL (AdWords Query Language) class, I'm still working on it but here's the easy setup ready to use, just have to change the

```
System.out.println(line);
```

to the [Cloud Storage Writer](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/googlecloudstorageclient/read-write-to-cloud-storage).

[At the function runExample](https://developers.google.com/adwords/api/docs/samples/java/reporting#stream-criteria-report-results)